# Alternative to __uuidof in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, directx, uuid, guid

I'm working with a C project that's using DirectX and I've run into a problem. Certain DX calls require a `IID` object, typically generated with `__uuidof`. One thing this is required for is creating a RenderTargetView. The DirectX samples/tutorials do this:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer );
```

When I try to call `__uuidof` in my C code, I get an compiler error: `Error 19  error C4233: nonstandard extension used : '__uuidof' keyword only supported in C++, not C`. DirectX has a C interface, so I imagine there must be a way to do this, but I have no idea what it would be. Anyone know?

Comment: C programmers typically just define the UUID as a constant somewhere in their source file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`__uuidof` is only available in C++, as error described. I think you already have definitions of the GUIDs of the interfaces for C available in DX header files.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/1306b57f-4b75-4f0c-b4f3-9bcc1e3a0dd6

From `d3d11.h`:

```
EXTERN_C const IID IID_ID3D11Texture2D;
```

Use this instead of `__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D)`.

Comment: Yep, that did it. The only other change I had to make was to link with `dxguid.lib`. Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted, it might be nice to add you'll also need to add the adress-of operator `&` if you are really using C. `ID3D10Texture2D* pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->lpVtbl->GetBuffer(swapchain, 0, &IID_ID3D10Texture2D, &pBackBuffer);`

Answer (score 2):

you have to find the uuid or "guid" of the class. it should be in some header in the directx sdk (older) or in the Platform SDK (on Windows Vista and Windows 7) - depends on what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the UIID of a class is defined in a C interface header file as the class name prepended by by the prefix "IID_" (see the accepted answer).
When creating plain C projects if you want keep using the C++ form you can create a simple macro:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define __uuidof(iid) IID_##iid
#endif
```

This will work if for the class IID exists a definition in the standard form IID_<classname>.