# __uuidof in C Master Volume Windows

Tags: c, windows, com, uuid

I want to change master volume with C, but `__uuidof` is only for C++; what can I use instead of that?

```
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
hr = CoCreateInstance(
     CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
     CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
     (void**)&deviceEnumerator);
```

I only found that: [Alternative to __uuidof in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868784/alternative-to-uuidof-in-c)

Comment: Wow! A question that actually deserves both C and C++ tag. :D

Comment: @klutt Not really, the question is not about C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to \_\_uuidof in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868784/alternative-to-uuidof-in-c)

Comment: Yes possible duplicate, I put this link in my post

Comment: I've seen the link, but so far you fail to explain how your question is different from the one you link. They appear to ask the exact same thing.

Comment: The other post does not really give the equivalent of __uuidof in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator` and `IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator` are defined [in your API's header file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371399(v=vs.85).aspx), i.e. `<mmdeviceapi.h>`.

You have to use these definitions in your C code, instead of `__uuidof`, as this is only available for C++ code.

Note that you need to include `<initguid.h>` before `<mmdeviceapi.h>`:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
```

Then this code should work:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    &CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, (*)
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL, 
    &IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,  (*)
    (void**)&deviceEnumerator
);
```

`(*)` Note that I've used the `&` (address-of), since in C++ you have references, but in C code you need to be explicit using pointers.

Comment: Thanks ! One last question, is it possible to use interface methods in C ? Like here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd371401(v=vs.85).aspx I have a problem with that : `hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);`

Comment: Yes, it’s possible to invoke COM interface methods in C, but the syntax is a bit more verbose than in C++. You have to specify the object pointer as first parameter (the implicit `this` in C++), and you must explicitly write the v-table pointer (`lpVtbl`), e.g. `hr = deviceEnumerator->lpVtbl->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(deviceEnumerator, /* other params ...*/);`. Some SDKs offer helper preprocessor macros to simplify the invoke syntax in C.

Comment: IMHO, you may consider using C++ to simplify your code, instead of using pure C.

Comment: I have to use libvlc too, do you think C ++ suits me?

Comment: As already written, I think C++ is a very good choice for COM programming (better than C). But I don’t know anything of libvlc.

Comment: The code is: `#include <initguid.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>

void main(){
 HRESULT hr;
 REFIID deviceEnumerator;
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    &CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL,
    &IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
    (void**)&deviceEnumerator);
}` but error is: undefined reference to __imp_CoCreateInstance, what's wrong?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd: You may want to search about the undefined `__imp_CoCreateInstance` error, and if you don't find anything, you may want to ask a new question. Anyway, if you search the [CoCreateInstance MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance), you'll find that you need to `#include <Objbase.h>`, and that you should link with the Ole32.lib import library. This library should be installed and in the search path. Do you have the Windows SDK installed?

Comment: @Mr.C64 Could we install it using MSYS2? Since I can't find Microsoft SDK package using `pacman` command in MSYS2. Is there any Microsoft SDK package manager for Windows 10?

Comment: @Mr.C64 Also `CoCreateinstance` function definition does exist in `msys64\minGW64\include\combaseapi.h` I wonder why it can't find the source code?! Maybe I need to include library path?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd I'm not familiar with MSYS2. I use Microsoft Visual Studio and the Microsoft Platform SDK. You may want to ask a new question about that.